# Html2Canvas es dependiente del porcentaje de ampliación de la pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, jspdf, html2canvas

Actualmente utilizo html2canvas para crear pdf conservando los diseños, pues requiero conservar el tamaño de la tabla, y el estilo cambiante de esta

Afortunadamente no tuve problemas en su implementación, sin embargo note que el tamaño de la pagina afecta en gran medida la resoluciones de la captura tomada, es decir, si amplio la pagina en un 200%, la captura se vera muy pequeña, por el contrario, si la ampliación es menor como por ejemplo 50% la captura se vera muy grande.

Es por ello que quisiera saber, ¿si existe alguna forma de evitar esto?, y en caso de no, ¿que otras librerías podría usar?